# Device Delete event Handling in Rule chain being able to reduce the total device count at Customer Level

Tags: thingsboard

I am using total count of devices as the "server attributes" at customer entity level that is in turn being used for Dashboard widgets like in "Doughnut charts". Hence to get the total count information, I have put a rule chain in place that handles "Device" Addition / Assignment event to increment the "totalDeviceCount" attribute at customer level. But when the device is getting deleted / UnAssigned , I am unable to get access to the Customer entity using "Enrichment" node as the relation is already removed at the trigger of this event. With this I have the challenge of maintaining the right count information for the widgets.

Has anyone come across similar requirement? How to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone come across similar requirement? How to handle this scenario?

What you could do is to count your devices periodically, instead of tracking each individual addition/removal.

This you can achieve using the [Aggregate Latest Node](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/pe/analytics-nodes/#aggregate-latest-node), where you can indicate a period (say, each minute), the entity or devices you want to count, and to which variable name you want to save it.

This node outputs a `POST_TELEMETRY_REQUEST`. If you are ok with that then just route that node to [Save Timeseries](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/action-nodes/#save-timeseries-node). If you want an attribute, route that node to a [Script Transformation Node](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/transformation-nodes/#script-transformation-node) and change the `msgType` to `POST_ATTRIBUTE_REQUEST`.